# How to align v axis label w.r.t chart window in google charts?

Tags: charts, bar-chart, text-alignment, google-visualization

The y asis labels of my google charts are aligned with respect to the vertical bar while I want them to be aligned with the margin of the chart. I looked everywhere. Can anyone help. The left to right and right to left uses thechart margin as reference not the chart area left margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no options for label alignment...

but you can move them manually when the chart's `'ready'` event fires

you can use the following chart method to get the bounds of each label

`getChartLayoutInterface().getBoundingBox(id)`

then set the labels's `x` attribute to the same value as the `width`
if the labels need more room, use option --> `chartArea.left`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
  data.addRows([
     ['Brain Tree', 200],
     ['One Touch', 220],
     ['PayPal Email', 240],
     ['PayPal Here', 260],
     ['PayPal Invoice', 280],
     ['PayPal Mas', 300]
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function (gglClick) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(gglClick));
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var labelIndex = -1;
    var labelWidth;

    var axisLabels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(axisLabels, function(label) {
      if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') {
        labelIndex++;
        labelWidth = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#label#' + labelIndex).width;
        label.setAttribute('x', labelWidth);
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, {
    chartArea: {
      left: 128
    },
    height: 600
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide is-stacked as true in option if you want to align Y-axis names with bar

options={ isStacked: true}